# Switch calls multiple cases one after another when checking table view tag

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, switch-statement

I have a `collection view` with three different cells. Each of the cells contains a `table view`. So, there are three `table view`s. I've set tags for each of them (from 1 to 3). 
Now, on my `view controller` (I set it as the `table view`'s `data source` when I dequeue `collection view`'s cells) I call `table view`'s `data source` method for the number of rows. To distinguish `table view`s I check each one's tag. Here is the code for that:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    switch tableView.tag {

    case 1:
        if unitItems1 != nil {
            return unitItems1!.count
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    case 2:
        if unitItems2 != nil {
            return unitItems2!.count
        } else {
            return 4
        }
    case 3:
        if unitItems3 != nil {
            return unitItems3!.count
        } else {
            return 4
        }
    default:
        return 0
    }
}
```

The problem is, when the first cell of the `collection view` is shown (with the first `table view`) it works fine. But when I scroll to the second cell, BOTH `case 2` and `case 3` get executed. After that, the second `table view` shows data as expected, but when I scroll to the third one, the method doesn't get called.

I can't figure out why two `case` statements get called one after another, while everything works fine for the first cell. If you have any ideas why this happens (or maybe, you could suggested a better way of checking `table view`'s), I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Unrelated to your actual question but you can simplify each `case` by replacing the `if/else` with something like `return unitItems2?.count ?? 4`.

Comment: @rmaddy, thanks for your suggestion. I'll definitely change that part!

Comment: I would verify that the tableView pointers are actually the same. numberOfRowsInSection is likely executing more than once because it is being called by multiple instances of UITableView as opposed to falling through the switch statement like you think it is.

Comment: @Dare, sorry, but what do you mean by saying "tableView pointers"?

Comment: Your collectionView is likely dequeuing the 2nd and 3rd cells, so you are getting one call for the table in cell 2 and another call for the table in cell 3 (actually, cells 1 & 2 because it's Zero-based).

Comment: @DonMag, so, you are saying that this happens, because my collection view is dequeuing the cell, right? But why in that case it dequeues second and third cells at the same time ONLY when I swipe to the second cell? When the first cell is showing, it doesn't dequeue other cells. And I changed tag numbers from storyboard, so they start from 1

Comment: When you swipe, it's possible you are moving slightly "into" the next cell, or the collection view is "pre-fetching" it. Either way, if you debug it that's almost certainly what's going on. As a side note, if you have a table view in each cell, it might make more sense to put the table view datasource and delegate handlers *in* the cell code, instead of trying to manage three different tables with one controller.

Comment: @DonMag, the third cell is dequeued when the second cell is just starting to become the visible one (the breakpoint for the third cell fires as soon as I swipe to the second cell). So, I think there is no way that the third cell moves onto the screen, because even the second cell isn't completely on the screen at that time. Also, I've seen a lot of examples where data sources and delegates are the cells themselves (and I'm sure that that would be easier to handle), but doesn't this violate MVC pattern? I mean, cells are views and they shouldn't know anything  about data.

Comment: MVC pattern can be considered a "guideline", and there is no lack of discussion / debate about it. However, putting a tableview inside a collection view cell is *also* "recommended against." That said, you can also create separate delegate / dataSource classes, and assign those (which would be more in line with MVC).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166767/discussion-between-tigran-iskandaryan-and-donmag).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the solution is quite simple. The reason of the problem was that `collectionView`'s data source method was dequeueing all the cells one after another, even when they weren't on the screen. Consequently, `tableView`'s inside of each cell were getting set, too. So, their data source method was getting called, hence the problem.

`UICollectionView` has a property called `isPrefetchingEnabled`. According to the documentation it denotes whether cells and data prefetching is enabled. 
The documentation says:

> When true, the collection view requests cells in advance of when they will be displayed, spreading the rendering over multiple layout passes. When false, the cells are requested as they are needed for display, often with multiple cells being requested in the same render loop. Setting this property to false also disables data prefetching. The default value of this property is true.

So, to solve the problem, described in the question, I set it to `false` as soon as my `collectionView` gets set.